# Output HTML and Download a File with PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to create a 'download' page for my website. I'm using a url like this: `http://example.com/download?file=21`. The actual location of the file on the server is stored in a database along with the file ID. I would like the download page to display the name of the file that is being downloaded along with some other HTML. I'm having trouble figuring out how to both download a file and display output on the same PHP page.

All the advice I've seen for actually downloading a file with PHP requires changing the headers. Do I need to display the download page and then download the file with something like AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it without ajax.

I would create a script to show the file with other html info `http://example.com/file?id=21` and if the download param is set ( `http://example.com/file?id=21&download=1` ) that script only prints the headers and sends the file.

Then, in `http://example.com/file?id=21` I would create an empty iframe (in the code or dynamically with javascript) and then when a user wants to download the file you just have to set the url of that iframe to `http://example.com/file?id=21&download=1` and the file will start to download. No need of ajax or reloading the website, only javascript to set the iframe url at the moment the user wants to download the file.

It's not the only way but I think it's a good one.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought about using a hidden iframe.

Comment: Actually I've searched a little and I've seen a jquery lib to download files and it also uses an iframe http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/